# Use "Sort" component in Web Framework category of iReports (for HTML Jasper Report)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to create a table that will be inserted as HTML code in a web page.

I have created a table but I cannot find any information/documentation of what should I do to be able to sort ASC or DESC by clicking on the column's headers.

I've been able to find the SORT component in the palette (Web Framework category) but I would need someone to explain how it must be used, and I also tried by adding the SORT BY options by editing the data-source's query. All I got was the report sorted correctly, but the ▲ symbol in the header is just a character (while clicking it, no action is performed).

What I need to do is to be able to sort by some of the columns dynamically, I will appreciate any help that could be given to me.